# Javascript: How to create an array with 'x' number of properties from another array?

Tags: javascript, arrays

I would like to transform the following array

```
[{
   0-1s: 6,
   1-2s: 2,
   country: "us"
}, {
   0-1s: 1,
   1-2s: 4,
   country: "ja"
}, {
   0-1s: 3,
   1-2s: 9,
   country: "ca"
}]
```

Into an array like this:

```
[{
   time: "0-1s",
   us: 6,
   ja: 1,
   ca: 3
},{
   time: "1-2s",
   us: 2,
   ja: 4,
   ca: 9
}]
```

The idea is to pivot my array and make the country fields a new property and the time it took for each country a bucket so no matter how many countries, I only have 2 elements in my array (with as many countries as properties) This is just an example and I have 40+ countries. However, I haven't been able to figure out how can I achieve this new data structure in plan JavaScript.

How should I approach this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use [`reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) to group them in to an accumulator object with `"0-1s"` and `"1-2s"` as keys. Then use [`Object.values()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_objects/Object/values) to get the array of values:

```js
const input = [{
   "0-1s": 6,
   "1-2s": 2,
   country: "us"
}, {
   "0-1s": 1,
   "1-2s": 4,
   country: "ja"
}, {
   "0-1s": 3,
   "1-2s": 9,
   country: "ca"
}]

const grouped = input.reduce((r, o) => {
  r["0-1s"] = r["0-1s"] || { time: "0-1s" };
  r["1-2s"] = r["1-2s"] || { time: "1-2s" };
  
  r["0-1s"][o.country] = o["0-1s"]
  r["1-2s"][o.country] = o["1-2s"]
  
  return r;
}, {})

console.log(Object.values(grouped))
```

If each object has more dynamic time ranges like `0-1s` etc, you could [destrcuture](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment) the object in the `reduce` parameter to get the `country` and `rest` of the time ranges to separate properties. Loop through the [**`entries`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/entries) of `rest` to update value for each `time` range:

```js
const input = [{"0-1s":6,"1-2s":2,country:"us"},{"0-1s":1,"1-2s":4,country:"ja"},{"0-1s":3,"1-2s":9,country:"ca"}];

const grouped = input.reduce((r, { country, ...rest }) => {
  Object.entries(rest).forEach(([time, v]) => {
    r[time] = r[time] || { time };
    r[time][country] = v
  })

  return r;
}, {})

console.log(Object.values(grouped))
```

Comment: Wow... wasn't aware of the reduce method. This is almost perfect! Would be possible to also include the time as a property afterwards?. I'll mark your answer as accepted once SO allows me

Comment: @user3587624 forgot about that. Also, added anothe approach to get the dynmaic number of time range properties

Comment: This works like a charm. I really appreciate it. I will continue learning on the reduce method. Looks very powerful!

Comment: I liked your second solution alot. Simple fast and efficient. I thought alot but can't get to your approach.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a little more dynamic code using `reduce()`. First get array of unique keys i.e `['0-1s','1-2s']` then convert that to object. Then use `reduce()` on the `arr` and add the properties to it.

```js
const arr = [{
   '0-1s': 6,
   '1-2s': 2,
   country: "us"
}, {
   '0-1s': 1,
  '1-2s': 4,
   country: "ja"
}, {
   '0-1s': 3,
   '1-2s': 9,
   country: "ca"
}]

const obj = [...new Set(arr.map(x => Object.keys(x).filter(a => a.includes('-'))).flat())].reduce((ac,a) => (ac[a]=({time:a}),ac),{});

const res = arr.reduce((ac,a) => {
  Object.keys(a).forEach(x => {
    if(x.includes('-')) ac[x][a.country] = a[x];
  })
  return ac;

},obj)

console.log(Object.values(res))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try like this in a modular way (the concept of reusability).

> I have used **map()** method defined on arrays to create new arrays.
>
> **Note:** You can define keys to stop unnecessary iterations or if your array is huge and most of the keys are matched then no problem.

```
// function 1
function getNewArray(arr) {
    let newArr = [];

    if(arr.length) {
        let keys = ["0-1s", "1-2s"];

        newArr = keys.map((key) => {
            let newObj = {}
            // console.log(newObj, key)

            for(let obj of arr) {               
                if(newObj["time"] === undefined) {
                    newObj["time"] = key
                }
                newObj[obj["country"]] =obj[key]
            }

            return newObj
        })
    } 

    return newArr
}

// function 2
function test() {
    let arr = [{
           "0-1s": 6,
           "1-2s": 2,
           country: "us"
        }, {
           "0-1s": 1,
           "1-2s": 4,
           country: "ja"
        }, {
           "0-1s": 3,
           "1-2s": 9,
           country: "ca"
        }]

    let newArr = getNewArray(arr)
    console.log(newArr)
    /*
        [ { time: '0-1s', us: 6, ja: 1, ca: 3 },
      { time: '1-2s', us: 2, ja: 4, ca: 9 } ]
    */

    /* --- Pretty printing --- */
    console.log(JSON.stringify(newArr, null, 4))
    /*
        [
            {
                "time": "0-1s",
                "us": 6,
                "ja": 1,
                "ca": 3
            },
            {
                "time": "1-2s",
                "us": 2,
                "ja": 4,
                "ca": 9
            }
        ]
    */
}

// Start
test()
```